# Copying only a table's columns from one database to another

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have found similar questions here in Stack Overflow but instead of copying a table's data, I just want to copy the columns with their names and datatypes.

For example, if I have a table named `users` in database `db1`:

```
id UUID
name VARCHAR(20)
registered BOOLEAN
```

How do I copy these columns with their name and datatypes to `db2`? (Without copying the rows of the table, just the columns)

I am using PostgreSQL.

Thank you!

Comment: What sort of context is this for? You could probably export the SQL script used for constructing either the table or the database, and copy it to another table or database and run it there. Or are you hoping for an automated version of this process?

Comment: @James hey! recently I had to create a new database for testing purposes. unfortunately the table I have has a lot of columns and I did not copy the SQL script. I understand I can do this manually but would like to know if PostgreSQL offers a command to do it faster if I forget to copy the script again in the future

Comment: Have you got pgAdmin on your computer? You can right-click on the table, select "Backup" and then in dump options select "Only schema" out of all the options. This will export you an SQL file you can run in another table. Otherwise using psql shell, you can run the pg_dump command in this format `pg_dump -t table_to_copy source_db | psql target_db`. Searching more about this command will help you structure it in the exact way you want.

Comment: Is `pg_dump` with `--schema-only` what you are looking for?  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-pgdump.html

Comment: @doctore @James thank you. i managed to copy them using `pg_dump`!